# Can't resolve module after npm-link for shared component repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, components

It is my first time trying npm-link, trying to create a shared component repository, and have hit an issue. I think I have linked the projecteds correctly as this message is displayed:

`/Users/tom.allen/Development/main/project/node_modules/@linked/project -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@linked/project -> /Users/tom.allen/Development/shared_component_lib`

The module is showing fine the the node_modules folder, however, when I try to add the component I created in the @linked/test repository I get an error saying:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@linked/project' in '/Users/tom.allen/Development/...'`

In the package.json for shared_component_lib i have:

```
  "name": "@linked/project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  },
```

I am exporting the component as:
`export { default as Hello } from './Hello';`

and importing as:
`import {Hello } from '@linked/project';`

I have triple checked for spelling mistakes and had a look over the webpack config (which is far from a strong point for me) but can't really see where i've gone wrong.

Apologies in advance if this doesn't make much sense! Any help will be massively appreciated.

Comment: Did you see any errors while executing `npm link` in `shared_component_lib`. And does `index.js` exist in the root of your application. Usually should be in `lib/index.js` or `src/index.js`

Comment: Hi @nithin There weren't any errors when executing npm link. Index.js is in the src folder, so src/index.js.

Comment: Can you update `shared_component_lib` package.json to  `"main": "src/index.js"` and then run `npm link` in `shared_component_lib` and `npm link @shared/project` in main project.

Comment: Let me know the results after you do the same. I'm suspecting this error will go away but another error should pop up :)

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should edit the  package.json in `shared_component_lib` from  `"main": "index.js"` to the actual location of file

ex:-  `"main" : "lib/index.js"` or `"main": "src/index.js"`